# Why isn't user prompted for input after end of file indicator is cleared?

Tags: c, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Why isn't the user prompted to enter input for the second `while` loop, even though the end of file indicator has been cleared?

*Note that the following code is being run on Bash on Windows (Windows Sub-System for Linux).*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    printf("Reading from stdin\n");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("End of file reached\n");

    printf("End of file indicator %s\n", (feof(stdin)) ? "not cleared" : "cleared");

    printf("Clearing end of file indicator\n");
    clearerr(stdin);
    printf("End of file indicator %s\n", (feof(stdin)) ? "not cleared" : "cleared");

    printf("Continue reading from stdin\n");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("End of file reached, all done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**INPUT:**

```
one
two
Ctrl+D
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Reading from stdin
one
two
End of file reached
End of file indicator not cleared
Clearing end of file indicator
End of file indicator cleared
Continue reading from stdin
End of file reached, all done
```

Comment: FYI: I tried this on a real Linux system and it worked as you'd expect there. So this looks like it really is WSL-related.

Comment: Can reproduce on a WSL system, it's certainly a WSL bug.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That's great, thank you very much for confirming this for me.  I really appreciate it.  Cheers!

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk Thank you also for confirming this for me.  I really appreciate it.  Cheers!

Comment: Is it a bug? I don't think the C Standard requires stdin to be recoverable from EOF condition

Comment: Compiled with MinGW-W64 (GCC 8.1.0) it resumes reading in `cmd`. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @thebusybee Thank you for confirming as well, I really appreciate it, cheers!